# Convert between spiral coordinates and axial coordinates in hexagon grid

Tags: math, coordinate-systems, hexagonal-tiles

I'm making a hexagon tile based game, which generates a honeycomb arrangement of hexagons in a spiral shape. My goal is to convert a world position (e.g. a mouse click) to a spiral coordinate (index / layer / position around layer). I can't think of how to do this, so instead I've been looking to simplify the problem by converting to/from axial coordinates first. How can this be done?

My configuration is pointy-topped as follows:
[image: spiral coordinates layer/position]

And here are the spiral indexes:
[image: spiral coordinates index]

Axial Coordinates for reference:

[image: axial coordinates]

I already have these equations for spiral coordinates:

```
const Layer = (index: number): number => {
    return Math.floor((3 + Math.sqrt(12 * index - 3)) / 6);
}
const Position = (index: number, layer: number): number => {
    return index - 3 * layer * (layer - 1) - 1;
}
const Index = (layer: number, position: number): number => {
    return 3 * layer * (layer - 1) + 1 + position;
}
```

Comment: What does index refer to?

Comment: @Caleth edited to add that info. They are how the spiral is stored in an array, and an index can be converted to and from the position/layer.

Comment: Canonical reference for hexagonal grids - https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/. I don't know if it answers your question(s).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, unfortunately, that resource only gives solutions for cubic/axial/offset/doubled systems, not spiral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for an answer to this question which did not require conditionals. The solution I've come up with is based on the spiral algorithm from [Amit Patel's Hex Grid Guide](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/).

It relies on the fact that you can sum and scale axial coordinates. A hex has 6 neighbors which have the relative axial coordinates of [(1, 0), (1, -1), (0, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 1)]. You can define any hex as a sum of two of these relative axial coordinates. I don't know quite how to explain this in words so diagram:
[image: Explanation of how to find an example hexagon (in this case hexagon 23) by summing two neighbor axial vectors [-3, 0] and [0, -2]]

My diagram is for "flat-topped" hexagons, but the logic is the same for "point-topped". The steps to calculate the axial position are.

1. Calculate the layer number, and the position.
2. Add one to the position and modulus by 6*layer. This isn't strictly necessary, but makes it follow the same index structure from before.
3. divide the position by the layer and floor. This gives you the direction "around" the layer. In the diagram this is the vector [0, -1].
4. add 4 to the direction and modulus by 6. Depending on if you do flat-topped or point-topped this may change so experiment. Ensure that your list of axial neighbor vectors are in a "loop". The list I shared above works perfectly. This gives you the direction "out to" the layer. In the diagram this is the vector [-1, 0].
5. Multiply the "out to" vector by the layer number, and the "around" vector by the position modulus the layer number.
6. Sum the two final vectors together, and ta da axial coordinate!

A Python implementation of this could be:

```py
neighbor_vec = ((1, 0), (1, -1), (0, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 1))

layer = int(3 + Math.sqrt(12 * index - 3)) // 6
position = (index - 3 * layer * (layer - 1)) % (6 * layer)

direction = position // layer
along = neighbor_vec[direction]
out_to = neighbor_vec[(direction + 4) % 6]

along_scale = position % layer

q = along[0]*along_scale + out_to[0]*layer
r = along[1]*along_scale + out_to[1]*layer
```

Comment: Thank you, nice find! Should I accept this answer instead?

Comment: If you feel like it answers your question better feel free to.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the individual cases as follows. Here `L` is layer, `P` is position, `(x, y)` are the axial coordinates; coordinates are in agreement with your images.

From `(L, P)` to `(x, y)`:

```
if L == 0:
   return (0,0)

otherwise:
k = floor(P/L) mod 6
j = P mod L

k   x     y     z
-------------------
0   j     L-j   -L
1   L     -j    j-L
2   L-j   -L    j
3   -j    j-L   L
4   -L    j     L-j
5   j-L   L     -j
```

From `(x, y)` to `(L, P)`:

```
z = -x-y
L = max(abs(x), abs(y), abs(z))

  x    y    z       P
------------------------
>=0  >=0              x
      <0   <0     L - y
>=0       >=0    2L + z
 <0   <0         3L - x
     >=0  >=0    4L + y
 <0        <0    5L - z
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test this.

You may also be able to fold some of the cases by exploiting the symmetry, but coding these directly may be easier, albeit a bit more verbose.

You already coded the functions to go between `(L, P)` and spiral.

Comment: I think this is close, but when testing, I got a weird result. See: [images](https://imgur.com/a/Km3s1ag)

Comment: @Jomity I don't think you coded it right; e.g. for `x=1`, `y=0`, we get: `z=-1`, `L=1`, and through the first case (`x>=0, y>=0`): `P=x=1`. So the value should be `(1,1)`, but in your first image you have `(-1,1)`.

Comment: Haha yes, my compiler failed to mention I had omitted all my `break` statements. My bad. Thank you!!